# TCP Socket IOExceptionbind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

After seeing several posts about this error, I don't really understand why the sometimes I am getting this exception

I saw several posts here that suggested to do a loop over binding the socket, but I think it should be executed once and there is a problem somewhere else.

This is my code:

```
 public ServerNetworkThread()
    {
        setName("ServerNetworkThread");
        _port = Logics.getInstance().getSharedPrefsManager().getInt(SharedPreferencesManager.SERVER_PORT_KEY, Consts.SERVER_PORT);
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler h)
    {
        _handler = h;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {    
        _isWorking = true;
        try
        {
            _serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            _serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            _serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(_port));

            while (_isWorking)
            {
                _socket = _serverSocket.accept();
                _socket.setSoTimeout(Consts.CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
                readDataTest();
            }    
        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logger.d("anton", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logger.d("anton", "server thread IOException" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private void readDataTest() throws IOException
    {
        //          BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-16LE")));
         //          BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-16LE")));
        InputStream iStream = _socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(iStream, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        int lettersCount = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
        String request = new String(buf,0,lettersCount);
//      request = request.split(Consts.EOF)[0];
        Log.d("test","server got request="+request);

        String responseStr = parseResponse(request);
        byte[] response = responseStr.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        outToClient.write(response);
        outToClient.flush();
        outToClient.close();
        in.close();
        _socket.close();
    }
```

This is my exception:

```
W/System.err( 1433): java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
W/System.err( 1433):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.bind(IoBridge.java:89)
W/System.err( 1433):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:150)
W/System.err( 1433):    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
W/System.err( 1433):    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:282)
W/System.err( 1433):    at com.example.visionixpanel.logics.network.ServerNetworkThread.run(ServerNetworkThread.java:61)
W/System.err( 1433): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
W/System.err( 1433):    at libcore.io.Posix.bind(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1433):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.bind(ForwardingOs.java:40)
W/System.err( 1433):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.bind(IoBridge.java:87)
W/System.err( 1433):    ... 4 more
```

It is thrown by this line:

```
 _serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(_port));
```

**update:**

I also have this code:

```
public void stopThread()
{
    _isWorking = false;
    try
    {
        if (_serverSocket != null)
        {
            _serverSocket.close();
        }
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            _socket.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Maybe is something to do with cleaning the thread sockets resources?

Comment: it seems that the port number or ip address that you are try to use is busy!

Comment: and what I need to do if it busy? I need to get a feedback from the server, can I force close it?

Comment: i am not sure if it is possible. but at first make sure that your ip is busy. to do this using code, try "InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut)". because it is possible that your program it self try to connect to that ip more than one time.

Comment: Try adding `clientSocket.setReuseAddress(true);` before binding the socket to an address (suggested in many similar questions on SO)

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 I already have this line on my main post

Comment: I updated my main post, thanks for help guys!

Comment: just to make it clear, `setReuseAddress(true)`  will be useful in case the connection using the same port is in `TIME_WAIT` state, but in case it still active this will do nothing

Comment: If you don't mind the port used, specify a port of 0 to the ServerSocket constructor and it will listen on any free port and you wont have this error.

Comment: the problem is I need to listen to a specific port for the communications to work properly

Comment: The problem is either that some prior process has the same need, or you are running multiple instances of your own application. In both cases your need is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really understand why the sometimes I am getting this exception

The port you are binding to is already in use.

> I saw several posts here that suggested to do a loop over binding the socket, but I think it should be executed once and there is a problem somewhere else.

I agree. The problem is that some other process is already using the port. Possibly for example a prior invocation of your application. Make sure it has exited. If it isn't that, you will have to either find what process it is and take whatever remedial action is appropriate, or use a different port number.

I see you're already using `setReuseAddress(true)` which solves the most common case of this.

> Maybe is something to do with cleaning the thread sockets resources?

No.

Comment: just to make it clear, `setReuseAddress(true)`  will be useful in case the connection using the same port is in `TIME_WAIT` state, but in case it still active this will do nothing

Comment: So what is your suggestion, can I clear all the ports the application is using  currently when this issue occurs?

Comment: Maybe I need to use Executors.newFixedThreadPool for working on each of my requests that were send by the server?

Comment: @visionixvisionix My suggestion is contained in my answer, and it doesn't contain anything about 'clear[ing] all the ports the application is currently using'. If the application is trying to bind a new `ServerSocket` to a port it is already using, there is something seriously wrong with it that should be sorted out prior to compile time. Fiddling around with thread pools is not going to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't really understand when this could occur, could it be something with the router?

Comment: @visionixvisionix I have told you when it occurs. What part of 'the problem is that some other process is already using the port' don't you understand? It has nothing to do with the router.

Comment: I did not install any new application on this device, we are using 11001 port for binding in the server thread. most of the application are using 8080/8081/8082 11001 is not unique but not that frequently used port

Comment: So yours is the only software running? Really? So the port isn't in use and the exception is a delusion? NB port 8080 is rather commonly used. I have eight Tomcats using it for example.